# How to run .net application on Linux environment?

Tags: .net, linux

Is it possible to run a .net application on Linux environment? If yes then how? Will all the components of .net framework work properly on Linux ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168170/do-net-applications-run-on-linux .  The answer is generally yes, but the libraries naturally tend to lag.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DotGNU

Comment: How we can run on mono?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please see [Running .Net applications on Linux with Mono](http://www.linux.com/archive/articles/53582):

> Imagine the fate of your company rests
>   on your completing your new Linux
>   project on time. You have a crack team
>   of first-class developers, but they're
>   all .Net programmers. What are you
>   going to do? Admit that Windows is
>   better that Linux? Cry? Resign? No,
>   you're going to install Mono and save
>   the world!

Comment: The link seems to point to somewhere else (so, broken?), and the comment is...

Comment: Could you pls elaborate?

Comment: the above link seems to redirect to a 2 sentence article titled: "Articles about Code Red are invading the Internet" that seems pretty irrelevant

I'm not totally sure, but did a quick search and it seems this is the updated link: 
https://www.linux.com/news/running-net-applications-linux-mono/

Answer (score 6):

While there are alternatives (I believe), [Mono](http://mono-project.com) is probably what you want.

It doesn't support *everything* that .NET supports, but there's a [compatibility tool](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) which will check for you. (I wouldn't blindly trust the results of the compatibility tool to be 100% accurate, as there will always be a few sneaky unknown incompatibilities, but it's a very good start.)

Comment: What is "do not trust" supposed to mean? Mono is not a panacea, but it's clearly useful in many cases.

Comment: @Matthew: Your comment was probably more to fm than my answer, but I meant I wouldn't trust the results of MoMA 100%. Will edit answer to make that clearer.

Comment: What I meant was it's bound to fail in the first run even though you think you did everything right. Personally I've been through the pain of porting a .NET app to Mono and it's just not straight forward and there are stuff just not supported or doesn't work as expected. I'm not even gonna talk about the compiler (if you compile it under mono, it's even worse).

Answer (score 5):

A new answer for an old question, as technology improves.
You might also consider running your app as a dotnet core application.
The same code will work nativly with MAc Windows and linX 
download dotnet runtime for your OS and on a console type
Dotnet .\yourapp.dll

Answer (score 2):

There is also [MainSoft](http://www.mainsoft.com/products/vmw_j2ee.aspx) that lets you run on J2EE environment on Linux. It basically compiles the .NET source into Java bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

An updated answer for **2018** with the current state of the [Mono Project in Linux](http://www.mono-project.com/).

[`mono` repos exist for](http://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin):

```
Ubuntu
Debian
Raspbian
CentOS
Fedora
Docker
```

The instructions suggest installing `mono-complete` - on Centos I also had to install `mono-basic` for VB.NET to work. The current level of support for VB.NET is:

```
default runtime: v4.0.30319
```

which is good enough to run a **VB.NET** `XML` client which required a `3.5` runtime:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For running simple .net Applications mono is the tool of your choice! I used it for many applications and it worked without major glitches. I would not reccommend starting to develop on Mono though. Some people in my Class tried to do C# on Linux with mono, and failed terribly.

When you do simple stuff it works good, but when you go to the more advanced stuff like using NHibernate or something like that, it may fail you. And you will miss out the best thing about .net - the Development Environment and that everything works together because everything is provided by Microsoft.