# Running .NET program in linux

Tags: .net, linux, code-translation

I have a C# project that uses another C++ project (.NET c++) as a dll. I have the source code for all of those. I want to run the program on Linux.
Is there a way to do that (to run .NET code on Linux) or do I have to manually translate the program to C or Java so it can be run on Linux?

Thanks

P.S
I found the following article (https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-compile-and-run-c-cplusplus-code-in-linux/) that just says i can compile C++ apps on Linux. So to everybody who says C++ can't be run on Linux, i would like a clarification please. (Because as i said - i DO have the source code, so can i just compile the program to run on Linux?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run .net application on Linux environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887193/how-to-run-net-application-on-linux-environment)

Answer (score 3):

Unless the ".NET C++" portion (I presume you actually mean C++/CLI, since Managed C++ Extensions for .NET is abandoned over a decade ago) is compiled with `/clr:pure`, there will be some porting required.

Pure MSIL assemblies, such as are created by the C# compiler, can execute directly on Linux with the help of Mono.

There is a new .NET runtime for Linux directly from Microsoft, the .NET Core, but it is focused on web services.  If you have a console application, .NET Core might be sufficient, but since it lacks any of the GUI frameworks, most likely you will still need to use Mono.

Comment: So do i just install .NET core (or equivalently Mono) on my Linux computer and i can simply run my .NET application? (it's a console application, so no GUI).

Comment: @scifie: For a lot of .NET applications, yes.  For yours in particular, it will depend on whether you're using any libraries that aren't part of Mono's version of the base class library.  Pure MSIL libraries can be copied across just like the application, but if they have any p/invoke calls, porting is needed.  And C++/CLI parts require porting.

Comment: Also, how do i know which type of C++ do i have? And as i said, i have the source code, so i can compile it any way you want. I just want it to be able to run as smoothly as possible on Linux

Comment: what if i use .NET Core - is it better for this scenario then Mono? I don't have experience with either of those

Comment: @scifie: Concerning the C++ portions, read the link I left in a comment to Sinoheh's answer.  It outlines quite a few approaches.

Comment: @ Ben Voigt What if i use .NET Core - is it better for this scenario then Mono? I don't have experience with either of those

Comment: As to C++, i didn't quite see a solution in that thread. So basically i will need to port at least the C++ part? I guess i can translate it to C#, if the C# part of my project works under .NET Core or Mono anyway, right? Or is there a better approach for the C++ part?

Comment: @scife: Any parts written in plain C++ can be left that way.  If C++/CLI is being used as interface code, it can be rewritten as p/invoke.  If you're actually using the full power of C++/CLI (e.g. template member functions in managed types) then neither route is going to be particularly easy -- C# generics are a good bit different from C++ templates, and on the other hand C++ template code relies on smart pointers for memory management instead of garbage collection.

Comment: Could you please clrify what you meen by "can be left this way"? Can i just compile them somehow to run on Linux? Or do you mean to translate them to C# without much hassle? Also, what do you mean by "f C++/CLI is being used as interface code"? Interface to what? Thanks

Comment: @scife: Linux has very good C++ compilers, including `clang` and `g++`.  Not all C++ code is portable, but a lot is, and just recompiling that is enough.  The "interface" is sometimes also called "glue logic", primarily all it does is copy data between C# objects and C++ types.  Commonly seen when you already have a working complex C++ library that you want to use inside C#.  On Windows you have multiple options for writing the glue logic: C++/CLI, COM interop, p/invoke.  On Linux there is only p/invoke.